# How to insert calendar control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel. in that panel there is one text box for some input and another one for taking date from calendar control. I have put calendar control below the second text box(i.e. txtDate), but I don't want it to be displayed when the page is loaded, instead I want a small image of calendar and on clicking that image a calendar should pop up and selected date must be captured by txtdate textbox.

Please help me with .aspx and .cs file. I'm using asp.net with C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AJAX Calender Extender. Here is the Sample Markup Code:

```
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="ControlIDHere" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                        TargetControlID="TextBoxIDHere" PopupButtonID="CalenderImageIDHere" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: I m not getting CalenderExtender control option. I have installed AjaxControlToolkit

Comment: Did you register it in your aspx by using this directive:<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %> on top of your aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET based solution for calender control is best explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9057/An-ASP-NET-implementation-of-a-Pop-Up-Calendar)

But I would suggest you to go forward with Ajax based solution
[Ajax Calender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Calendar_Simple.ashx)

[Calender control in AJax toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can user use Jquery library in your project. Below is the example

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">        
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">    
    </script>
    <script >
        $(document).ready( function() {
                $("[id=^datepicker]").datepicker();
            } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>Date: <asp:TextBox   id="datepicker" runat="server">
    </p>

    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```